# What is the low frequency limit for ferrite cores in audio applications?

Tags: audio, transformer, inductor, ferrite

I've searched high and low through the ferrite magnetics catalogs and this list for an answer and can't find data on ferrite core permeability below 10kHz. My application is for audio use and I need to know how the permeability of the core drops off with falling frequency.

Ideally the permeability will drop rapidly at 300Hz, with some flexibility in the frequency. I imagine core losses will be small in this region since a lower permeability results in lower hysteresis losses. Also I suspect the core air gap will not play much of a role.

I know I came across this information many years ago but am having a problem finding it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$\mu_i\$ should not change much from DC to 10kHz, that's why the graphs will typically only show frequencies above 10kHz, for MnZn ferrites, for example.

Materials such as permalloy have noticeably lower permeability at 100Hz than at DC.

Comment: Maybe it was the permalloy curve I remembered.

Will it just be the primary inductance which limits the lower frequency, ignoring saturation?

Comment: Saturation, due to the low inductance, is what kills you at lower frequencies.

Answer (score 11):

There is no low frequency limit - I'm running 6.0 Hz through a ferrite transformer in order to provide signal isolation to a circuit. I can run it all the way up to 50 kHz too and, there is no change in amplitude.

What I have to be aware of is the low magnetization inductance that a hundred turns on an RM12 pot core produces. This, of course affects the lower frequencies much more hence, the overall low permeability of ferrites means that I can't reliably use them as 50/60 Hz AC mains transformers.

So, running them at 6.0 Hz means I cannot transfer watts of power so easily.

---

EDIT SECTION

You have to be aware of core saturation. The RM12 (3C90 material) pot core that I wound had 100 turns but only had a primary inductance of 56mH. So, at (say) 50Hz, this is an impedance of about 18 ohms. With 3C90 material, looking at the BH curve for the material, it "starts" to saturate at a magnetization (H) of about ~50 ampere turns per metre: -

[image]

What does that mean you might ask! The "/m" part is the effective length of the ferrite core i.e. the distance the magnetism "travels" around the core and for an RM12 this is about 57mm so, the number of ampere turns you can apply is 50 * 0.057 = 2.85 ampere turns. As I have 100 turns, this means the pot core will start to saturate at a current of 28.5 mA peak.

The RMS will be about 20mA - given the impedance at 50 Hz is only 18 ohms means a terminal voltage limit of about 0.36V RMS. At 1kHz, the impedance will be 20 times higher and therefore you can apply 7.2V RMS to the transformer before saturation starts to be seen.

So, ferrites have no low frequency limit providing you avoid saturation.

Comment: 57mm = 0.057m not .0057m, but the result looks OK to me.