# Ferrite N87 losses below 10 kHz

Tags: ferrite

I use ferrite N87 cores ([datasheet](https://en.tdk.eu/download/528882/3226013b0ed82a6a2af3666f537cbf83/pdf-n87.pdf)), and I would need losses in the frequency range 50 Hz to 10 kHz. The datasheet on page 5 specifies losses between 25 kHz and 600 kHz. I could try to interpolate with some effort, but I would prefer measured values.

Does anybody know a link to such data? Would you expect a significant slope change if I just interpolate with a straight line to the lower frequencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/117281

Comment: The losses at low frequencies are very low - maybe you can explain why you would wish to know them?

Comment: The core loss is pretty linear when plotted on log-log scales, so you could certainly interpolate with a straight line.  You're not likely to get a better answer than that without a lot of work.  However, like @Andyaka says these types of ferrites are really low loss at low frequencies like <10 kHz, so you can probably ignore the core losses for all practical purposes.

Comment: @MIL-SPEC: It's no duplicate, the linked question is not about losses but about permeability.

Comment: @ Andy aka: We do calorimetric loss measurements to get the winding losses of magnetic components, and I thought that I can, if employing ferrite, neglect the core losses, but unfortunately this is not the case (the winding losses are also small). So I have to consider the core losses.

Comment: @ John D:  After some more research I agree with you that a straight line will be a good approximation. I will write some scripts to do the job.

Comment: @UweD, it would be really helpful to the group if you could share your write-up (or a summary) as an answer to your own question. It is OK to answer your own question and accept the answer if you think it is the best answer. This group is built on goodwill and knowledge sharing. Quick technical note: Interpolation is estimating a value in between measured values. Extrapolation is estimating a value beyond the range of measured values.